# Match coloring of slices for series of pandas pie charts

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Judge': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 3, 8: 3}, 'Category': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'A', 4: 'B', 5: 'C', 6: 'A', 7: 'B', 8: 'C'}, 'Rating': {0: 'Excellent', 1: 'Very Good', 2: 'Good', 3: 'Very Good', 4: 'Very Good', 5: 'Very Good', 6: 'Excellent', 7: 'Very Good', 8: 'Excellent'}} )
```

I'm plotting a pie chart to show the ratings of each judge like this:

```
grouped = df.groupby('Judge')

for group in grouped:
    group[1].Rating.value_counts().plot(kind='pie', autopct="%1.1f%%")
    plt.legend(group[1].Rating.value_counts().index.values, loc="upper right")
    plt.title('Judge ' + str(group[0]))
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.ylabel('')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, the colors of the slices are different for each judge. For example, Judge 1's "Excellent" slice is blue where Judge 2's "Very Good" slice is blue.

How can enforce slice color consistency from plot to plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can unstack and plot:

```
axes = (df.groupby('Judge').Rating.value_counts()
   .unstack('Judge')
   .plot.pie(subplots=True, figsize=(6,6), layout=(2,2))
)

# do some thing with the axes
for ax in axes.ravel():
    pass
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: very useful!  but how would I go about adding titles and setting the legend positions of the subplot now that it's no longer a loop?

Comment: The above command returns a list (of lists) of axis instances. You can assign and modify the axes as you wish. See updates.